# linux - context-based access control

Tags: networking, network-namespaces

I would like to further restrict network traffic based on the source / destination application.  To do that, I'm using network namespaces, but is there a better / simpler approach?  My approach requires me to explicitly declare the network namespace that an application runs in, but is it possible that I can do so using another manner?  If so, what are my options?

Comment: What does "destination application" mean? And how do you want to filter by source application? Can you explain more specific?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what I was looking for was AppArmor or SELinux.  Alternatively, network namespaces could also be used.